# Redirection of user on change of selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to redirect the user on change of the selection?

html code

```
<select name="annee" ng-model="annee" ng-change="selectAnnee()"> 
    <option value="2000" ng-selected="2000==2014">2012</option>
    <option value="2001" ng-selected="2001==2014">2013</option>
    <option value="2002" ng-selected="2002==2014">2014</option>
</select>
```

js code

```
this.selectAnnee = function(){
window.location.href=link.substring(link.indexOf('/'),link.lastIndexO‌​f('/')) + '/fiche?type=' + this.type + '&annee=' + $scope.annee;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript/21396837#21396837

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti, I'm currently using this `this.selectAnnee = function(){window.location.href=link.substring(link.indexOf('/'),link.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/fiche?type=' + this.type + '&annee=' + $scope.annee;}` and it is not working.

Comment: add the script to the question

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti, post've been edited!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller , do this

```
$scope.selectAnnee = function(){
     $location.path("/REDIRECT_HERE");
}
```

In view

```
<select name="annee" ng-model="annee" ng-change="selectAnnee()"> 
    <option value="2000" >2012</option>
    <option value="2001" >2013</option>
    <option value="2002" >2014</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm currently using this `this.selectAnnee = function(){window.location.href=link.substring(link.indexOf('/'),link.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/fiche?type=' + this.type + '&annee=' + $scope.annee;}` and it is not working.

Comment: @user3821280 check your console, there you might find any error log